# Android - share (java code) number

Tags: android

How I share (java code) from my android application a phone number, so that it can mark it or send it by email **at a time**. 
Thank you very much

Here's my code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView txtphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtphone1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + txtphone.getText()));
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Throwable e) {
                message("ERROR: startActivity - " + e.toString());
                return;
            }

            return;
        }
```

Comment: Hello you want to share your phone number to email??

Comment: Number phone at phone and email at a time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void shareText(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull String text) {
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(text)
            .getIntent();
    if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

here's a great article about sharing - https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b#.ommhqdbhy